# Dynamic instantiation of Components?

Tags: angularjs, angular

**Update:** To clarify my sad verbiage below...

Given an array of JSON objects, a "Level" component and a "Sprite" component...

I'm stuck on the syntax to loop through the array and init a new "Sprite" for each JSON object and then add that "Sprite" to ... the template (?) of my "Level".

This is my "Level" template. I can hardcode the Sprite in and it works (as the image shows) but I'm scrambling to find the syntax to add an arbitrary number of Sprites.

```html
<div>
  <img src={ {imagePath}}/>
</div>
<div>
  <app-sprite></app-sprite>
</div>
```

---

I'm a refugee Flex/Actionscript developer and am learning Angular 2. I "get" lots of it – but then I get stuck.

My little exercise here: based on some JSON (hard-coded now but later to come from a Service) is to populate a "Level" component with a background image, and then create and position some "Sprites" on the "Level".

Here's the way it looks now:
[image]

I've created a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/X5i9dA6sVcTYVanS7NcG?p=preview) of what I am doing. Where I am confused:

- How do I dynamically create custom components the "angular" way? I've seen the tutorials with `*ngFor` to create `li` elements but the template for my "Sprite" component looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <img class="spriteFloater" src={{imagePath}}/>
</div>`
```

The above works if I hardcode the "imagePath" to a url – but if I try to use "eventData.imagePath" (where event data is a JSON obj) then it fails.

I can hard-code that a reference to that template into my "Level" ("app-sprite" tags) and it works but my attempts to generate "Sprites" on the fly have failed.

- Also, I am trying to pass data to each "Sprite" and then use it in my template. I tried doing it through the `constructor` but that didn't work so a created a custom function to do it – and while it outputs the correct data to the console, the "Sprites" I am creating are not the ones being injected into the DOM.

Geez... sorry this is such a stupid, wordy post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need to use

```
eventData?.imagePath
```

If you init data in `ngOnInit()` this is after Angular first tries to resolve bindings in the view. If `eventData` is `null` the access to `imagePath` throws. With `?.` Angular accesses `imagePath` only when `eventData` is `!= null`

Comment: Not sure what the expected behavior is. Should the `<app-sprite></app-sprite>` in `Level` be repeated or the `<div><img ...></div>` inside `Sprite` and how should it be repeated, on what data and what value should be used for what?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://plnkr.co/edit/WwdO21DT5qlwgEcxYL0L?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

With Günter's nudge I was able to come up with this. I didn't know the syntax to use `*ngFor` correctly and then I had to figure out how to apply the passed in data to the style of the newly created sprites.

Guess I am not in <s>Kansas</s> Flex/Actionscript any more. This stuff is crazy... but I like it (I think).

> ```
> <div>
>   <app-sprite *ngFor="let event of eventList" [eventData]="event"
>   ></app-sprite>
> </div>
> ```

[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Eventdata} from './eventdata'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sprite',
  template:`
     <div>
         <img class = "spriteFloater" [src]="eventData.imagePath"
                [style.left] = "eventData.x"
                [style.top] = "eventData.y"
                [style.background] = "eventData.id"/>
    </div>`,
  styles [`
    .spriteFloater {
      position: absolute;
      background: black;
      left: 50px;
      top:  80px;
    }
  `]
})
export class Sprite implements OnInit {
  @Input() eventData: Eventdata;
  setEventData(data:EventData){
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```